How to change Oracle Apex language dynamically?
I have an Oracle Apex Application (version 22) and I would like to change the application language without changing the URL of the application.
For some architecture reasons, the URL should not change (for example not adding any query string or parameter like: ?lang=SP).
I have tried :
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = 'BASQUE';

But it's not working.
I'm thinking about creating a before-header process and change the language at that level.
Is that possible?

I have a application process called set_language in PL/SQL as:
begin
owa_util.redirect_url('f?p=' || :APP_ID || ':' || :APP_PAGE_ID || ':' || :APP_SESSION ); 
end;

This process has a Request = Expression condition with expression for example "LANG":

Then, for example at the navigation bar, I have several list entries to let user change the language:

With the following setup:

(page value = &APP_PAGE_ID. to not change the page that user was already at)
And finally, I have a Application Item called 'FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE'.
With that given setup, the url stays the same when user changes the language.
Note that Application Item name should be exactly 'FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE' as it is the built-in naming for app language. More details are here.
